# As a Christian but not a Catholic, can I confess to a Catholic priest?

Tags: catholicism, confession

I am not a Catholic, but I am a Christian. I do not feel any desire to become a Catholic. I have been out of church for many years, and am not actively seeking a church to attend. However, I want to confess my sins.  Would I be able to go to Catholic confession?  I believe I would feel better if I could confess to someone who loves God and can be trusted to be discreet. God knows that I repent, but I still feel incomplete.  Maybe a I need a spiritual advisor rather than a confessor?

Comment: We can answer whether the Catholic church would permit you to confess to a Catholic priest. Answering what you should do is an entirely different matter. The best we can suggest in personal and spiritual matters is to seek the council of a trusted pastor, or other trusted advisor.

Comment: @SimplyaChristian  Any Christian using this sacrament is assured of peace of mind and that the seal of confession will not be broken!